# Aggregate values into a new column while retaining the old column

Tags: sql, hive

## **Question**

Say you have some simple data about some purchases:

| user_id | order_date | product_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | mon | 2e1 |
| 001 | mon | 44h |
| 001 | tues | e6f |
| 002 | wed | 6g3 |
| 002 | wed | 43m |
| 003 | wed | k19 |
| 003 | fri | 9d5 |

And I need to aggregate the product IDs into an array column, e.g. using `COLLECT_SET`, grouping by *user_id* and *order_date*. HOWEVER I also wish to retain the *product_id* column, as so:

| user_id | order_date | product_id | product_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | mon | 2e1 | `["2e1","44h"]` |
| 001 | mon | 44h | `["2e1","44h"]` |
| 001 | tues | e6f | `["e6f"]` |
| 002 | wed | 6g3 | `["6g3","43m"]` |
| 002 | wed | 43m | `["6g3","43m"]` |
| 003 | wed | k19 | `["k19"]` |
| 003 | fri | 9d5 | `["9d5"]` |

## **Problem**

I can easily create the array column with the following query:

```
SELECT user_id, 
       order_date, 
       COLLECT_SET(product_id) AS product_ids
FROM table t
GROUP BY user_id, order_date
```

But that way I don't get the *product_id* column for every row, which I need.

Meanwhile if I include the *product_id* as so:

```
SELECT user_id,
       order_date, 
       product_id, 
       COLLECT_SET(product_id) AS product_ids
FROM table t
GROUP BY user_id, order_date, product_id
```

Then the *product_ids* column will always be an array of length one, ie:

| user_id | order_date | product_id | product_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | mon | 2e1 | `["2e1"]` |
| 001 | mon | 44h | `["44h"]` |

And of course if I exclude *product_id* from the `GROUP BY` then I get an error: "**Expression not in GROUP BY key 'product_id**"

Is it possible to do this in a single simple query, without e.g. creating a temp table and then joining them on *user_id* and *order_date*? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The reason you're not getting the correct result is you're simply using the COLLECT_SET function on rows, grouping on all other columns (which would return the same table).

You can aggregate the table on user_id and order_date, and create an aggregate dataset. Then join the main table with this aggregated dataset based on those 2 columns and you'd get the expected result.

```
SELECT
    t1.user_id,
    t1.order_date, 
    t1.product_id, 
    t2.product_ids
FROM 
    table t1
LEFT JOIN (
    SELECT 
        user_id, 
        order_date, 
        COLLECT_SET(product_id) AS product_ids
    FROM 
        table t
    GROUP BY 
        user_id, order_date
) AS t2
```

Here's the query to do the same. First the main table, joined with the aggregate table, and the select table tables the `COLLECT_SET` result as `product_ids` column here.

The subquery would return the following dataset

| user_id | order_date | product_ids |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | mon | ["2e1","44h"] |
| 001 | tues | ["e6f"] |
| 002 | wed | ["6g3","43m"] |
| 003 | wed | ["k19"] |
| 003 | fri | ["9d5"] |

Then the overall query's result would be

| user_id | order_date | product_id | product_ids |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 001 | mon | 2e1 | ["2e1","44h"] |
| 001 | mon | 44h | ["2e1","44h"] |
| 001 | tues | e6f | ["e6f"] |
| 002 | wed | 6g3 | ["6g3","43m"] |
| 002 | wed | 43m | ["6g3","43m"] |
| 003 | wed | k19 | ["k19"] |
| 003 | fri | 9d5 | ["9d5"] |